# Why did Gman "extract" Alyx Vance from Black Mesa?

Tags: half-life-2, half-life-2-episode-two

In the cut-scene for Half Life 2: Episode 2 Gman says he "plucked" her from Black Mesa. Why?

Comment: We can all find out in the year 2017, when Valve finally releases HL2:E3.

Answer (score 10):

Speculatively, GMan is 'in control' of the timeline of the Half Life series - certainly in the opening speech he gives in Half Life 2 he gives the impression it's him pulling all the strings.  There are more references in his final speech of that game.

Given this, it's probably for the same reason he 'extracted' Gordon Freeman (or led him to safety, depends how you read his words from that speech I referenced earlier).  I'd say it's because Alyx is somehow needed to save the world.

Perhaps it could be said that GMan is somehow a 'protector' of the world, and that Alyx and Gordon are chosen as heroes for specific abilities they possess.  Alyx certainly seems to have an affinity with technology (see 'Dog' character from the series, and her proficiency with the gravity gun).

I think this is really as deep as one could go without resorting to making stuff up - it's already highly speculative and based on pretty thin strands of evidence.

Comment: Judging by his comments down the line he sounds more like a mercenary... Or at least, a procurer of mercenaries.

Comment: That certainly fits the narrative but I wonder for whom he is procuring the mercenaries in that case - and under what circumstances he offers his services.